# Import products and keeping the current id

Tags: products-management, import

Has anyone tried importing products from another store and keeping the same ID? I'm not sure how to do identity inserts with Magento. I'm sure there has to be a way.

Comment: I don't think there is a way.. Can I ask you why you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Well, it'll make what I have to do a whole lot easier since I'll be pushing data between two systems.

Comment: How are you currently planning on importing the products? Also I am assuming you are referring to the product_id. Are the foreign ids compatible with Magento's database column that stores the id (catalog_product_entity::entity_id), in other words is the ID always an integer of up to 10 digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is specifically why `SKU` exists, so you don't rely on the autoincrement, primary key to do syncs between databases.

If you have no other way of identifying the products in the second database(aka non-magento one), you can use the ID from it as a `SKU` in the magento database.

But I don't think there are product databases that don't use sku's for identification of products.

**PS:**
You can load/filter products by SKU just as easily as you can with ids.

```
// for example, to load a product with the sku "custom_sku"
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('custom_sku', 'sku');
```

Comment: I agree.  Why would you need the increment_id to be the same?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible - but the side-effects are not desirable. Basically, there are many `afterSave()` methods called after a new product is created (read: not updated). It is these functions that set up the required additional information in the DB (stocking, attribute, child/parent association, category assignation).

It is actually possible to set the product ID - and even make it look like it completed without error - but the reality is that further down the line; there'll be errors that cannot be explained - and it will fall on the initial import itself.

The ID really is merely for the database - not for the end user, this is why the SKU exists. You can easily keep stores in sync using the SKU - using any recognised method:

1. Magento Dataflow (standard import/export utility)
2. Magento SOAP API
3. Magento REST API
4. Aftermarket solutions (eg. uRapidFlow)

---

A good example is if you attempt the same process with categories; by [programatically creating them](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quick-script-batch-create-magento-categories/) and setting the ID simultaneously. The `children_count` parameter is overridden (event if explicitly set) by an `afterSave()` method.

Which allows the import to complete and for everything to see okay - but later breaks the conditional promotional rules category display. So then you are forced to run a [MySQL fix](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-category-children-count-fix/) to rectify it.